# How can I update the shared Object repository in QTP?

Tags: automation, qtp

Is there is any way to update shared OR(Object Repository) in QTP without having to copy all Objects into local then exporting. 
I have an issue that i want to update the Shared OR and I'm unable to do that. 
if any of you know....kindly help me.
your help is highly appreciated.

Thanks 
Manaysah

Comment: You want to Merge local repository into a shared repository?
BTW what issue you facing?

Comment: No , I just want to make the local copy of Object Repository(OR) shared for all actions.
and if there is way to copy all objects in OR at once, without having to copy each of them separated.

Comment: You need to understand the difference between local OR & shared OR.
If the objects are stored in the local object repository they are available for particular action only. If the objects are stored in the shared object repository they are available for entire application. Shared object repository occupies less memory than the local object repository, that is why it is preferable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your need, you have to update shared OR with Local OR.
Please find this [link](http://www.articlesontesting.com/2010/10/updating-shared-object-repository-from.html) for steps

Comment: thanks .... 

I understand, but i want to know if there is a way to copy all objects in the Repository to local to facilitate make changes to it and then exporting them to reusing them in as shared objects in other actions.

Comment: the issue solved using Object Repository manager. 
thanks very much the article was extermly useful.
your help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Could it be that you opened the Shared Object Repository (SOR) in read only mode?

When opening SORs they are opened by default as read-only, you can uncheck _"Open in read-only mode" when opening the SOR.

[image: SOR open dialog]

Or if the SOR is already open you can enable editing by pressing the *"Enable Editing"* button (**File -> Enable Editing**)

[image: Enable editing]